# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [ExpressionEngine® Answers](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Database error 1118 - Row size too large](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24378/database-error-1118-row-size-too-large)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Sorting / showing entries by author in control panel](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24360/sorting-showing-entries-by-author-in-control-panel)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can you control the pagination URL?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24262/how-can-you-control-the-pagination-url)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Show entries in a single category and then again in all categories except the previously excluded category](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24324/show-entries-in-a-single-category-and-then-again-in-all-categories-except-the-pr)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Conditional errors after upgrading to EE 2.9 (just a helpful hand)](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24474/conditional-errors-after-upgrading-to-ee-2-9-just-a-helpful-hand)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [EE Channels in Structure?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24433/ee-channels-in-structure)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Search: Simple Form](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24871/search-simple-form)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Expresso Store - upload multiple discount codes to be used once](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24604/expresso-store-upload-multiple-discount-codes-to-be-used-once)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [EE 2.8.1 & MSM Issue](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24327/ee-2-8-1-msm-issue)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Moving site to a new server](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24422/moving-site-to-a-new-server)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---